# Conditional Summary in R: MaxSum

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, summary

I'd have a data frame of authors in a much larger data set than the example in R that I'd like to get better descriptive's of.  I know (kinda of) how to get the `maxsum` but **how could I get the max summary of unique authors EXCEPT for the top 2 most frequent authors for example?** **How would I then be able to determine the new `maxsum`?** **How would I get the actual summary that the new `maxsum` would be 3 instead of an output of it?**

I'm basically looking for conditional way's of summarizing my data. Can anyone help me out in this department?

```
dat <- data.frame(author=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "a","a", "a", "c","c","c","c"),Post=c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one","one", "one","one", "one","one", "one","one", "one"))
authors <-dat[,1]
author_vec <- (authors)
length(unique(author_vec)) #5
ex_s <- summary(as.factor(neg.author_vec),maxsum=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using the `plyr` library:

```
require(plyr)
temp <- ddply(dat, ~author, summarise, sum=length(author))
temp <- temp[order(-temp$sum), ][3:nrow(temp), ]

> temp
  author sum
2      b   2
4      d   2
5      e   1
```

The authors `a` and `c` have been removed because they were two most frequently appearing authors in the data set.

Comment: How could I get the total sum of `temp$sum`?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear how many you expected after exclusion of the top 2. This assumes you wanted the next three in frequency (since you said you understood how maxsum was acting). If you wanted the next five, then add two to your current maxsum::

```
ex_s <- sort(summary(author_vec,maxsum=5), decreasing=TRUE)[-(1:2)]
ex_s
#------
b d e 
2 2 1
```

Comment: How would I get the actual summary that the new max sum would be 3 instead of an output of it?